# Maximal circle packing inside a given square

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

How to pack n equal disks(radius a/2) with maximal area  inside a given rectangle ?

I'm trying to solve this problem using Mathematicas Region functions.

Here my approach:

Maximize the area of the union of all disks `regK`and require all disks to lie inside the square `RegionWithin[rect,regK]`.

```
sys[a_?NumericQ, pts_ ?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] & )]:=Block[{
rect = Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}],
regK = RegionUnion[Map[Disk[#, a/2] &, pts]]}
,
{ Area[regK], 
Join[{RegionWithin[rect, regK] , 0 < a < 1/2}, 
Map[-1/2 < # < 1/2 &, Flatten[ pts]]]}]
```

Unfortunately

```
n=3;  (*number of circles*)
NMaximize[ sys[a, Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}]]
, Join[{a}, Flatten[Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1,n}]]]]
(*NMaximize::nnum: The function value {-0.835066,{-False,-False,-False,-True,-False,-True,-False,-False}}
is not a number at 
{a,x[1],x[2],x[3],y[1],y[2],y[3]} = {0.677613,0.614816,0.51572,0.66946,-0.0824906,0.251149,0.6107}.*)
```

`NMaximize` stops evaluation with an error message.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: The formulation is not clear to me: is `a` fixed in "radius `a/2` maximal"?

Comment: I'm looking for maximal  radius `a/2`.

Comment: See [that Maple application](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=153596) as an example (Preview of its as PDF file is available.). Good luck!

Comment: @user64494 Thanks, very interesting!

Comment: See this
https://www.zhihu.com/question/67716815/answer/401858575

Comment: Does it have to be with a Region function? maybe you could use `ShortestPathFunction[]` on permutations?

Comment: @Teabelly Interesting idea, thanks! `RegionWithin` is useful if  the enclosing boundary is modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

It seems that `RegionWithin` is better than the original method.

```
reg = Rectangle[];
n = 5;
sol = NMaximize[{r, r > 0, 
   Table[RegionWithin[reg, Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r]], {i, n}], 
   Table[SignedRegionDistance[RegionBoundary@reg]@{{x[i], y[i]}} >= 
     r, {i, n}], Table[{x[i], y[i]} \[Element] reg, {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[EuclideanDistance[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}] >= 2 r, {i, 
     n}, {j, i - 1}]}, {r, Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}]} // Flatten]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[], 
  Rectangle[], {FaceForm[Red], Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r], {i, n}]} /. 
   sol[[2]]}]
```

> `{0.207107, {r -> 0.207107, x[1] -> 0.207107, y[1] -> 0.792893,  x[2] -> 0.207107, y[2] -> 0.207107, x[3] -> 0.792893,  y[3] -> 0.792893, x[4] -> 0.792893, y[4] -> 0.207107, x[5] -> 0.5,  y[5] -> 0.5}}`

[image]

**Original**

For the $n$ points $p_i,i=1\cdots n$, we set
$$d(p_i,p_j)\geq 2r,i\not=j$$ and all the distance to the boundary of region $d(p_i,Boundary)\geq r$

```
reg = Rectangle[];
n = 5;
sol = NMaximize[{r, 
   SignedRegionDistance[RegionBoundary@reg] /@ 
     Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}] >= r, 
   Table[{x[i], y[i]} ∈ reg, {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[EuclideanDistance[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}] >= 2 r, {i, 
     n}, {j, i - 1}]}, {r, Table[x[i], {i, n}], Table[y[i], {i, n}]} //
    Flatten]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[], 
  Rectangle[], {FaceForm[Red], 
    Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r], {i, n}]} /. sol[[2]]}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.  I tried your solution for n=3 and got a "L-shaped" result which isn't optimal.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am using version 12.2 in Win and Linux.

Comment: The conditions `Flatten[{0 < r < 1, Table[{r <= x[i] <= 1 - r, r <= y[i] <= 1 - r}, {i, 1, n}], Table[Total[({x[i], y[i]} - {x[j], y[j]})^2] >= (2 r)^2, {i, n}, {j, i - 1}]}]` runs faster and gives a larger radius for `n == 5` but a smaller radius for `n == 6`.

Comment: @cvgmt My version 12.2/Win gives a different "optimal" solution, don't know why. Your modified answer shows what I would expect as an optimum!

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks, I test in my Linux , both of the two codes get the same radius. For n=6, r -> 0.187681, for n=5, r -> 0.196438

Comment: @cvgmt See my posted pseudo answer for `n=3, r=0.25` .

Comment: @cvgmt  Thank you for your modified answer. `RegionWithin` seems to be more "robust" . But still, for example `n=8`,  Mathematica doesn't find the global minimum (with four symmetry axes )

Comment: @UlrichNeumann For n=8,  r -> 0.169305?

Comment: @cvgmt n=8: r -> 0.17054! (see picture in my pseudo answer)

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer, but to long for a comment:**

Here is "my" result evaluated with Mathematica v12.2 and the approach from @cvgmt

```
reg = Rectangle[];
n = 3;

sol = NMaximize[{r, 
   SignedRegionDistance[RegionBoundary@reg] /@ 
     Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}] >= r, 
   Table[{x[i], y[i]} \[Element] reg, {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[EuclideanDistance[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}] >= 2 r, {i, 
     n}, {j, i - 1}]}, {r, Table[x[i], {i, n}], Table[y[i], {i, n}]} //
    Flatten]
(*{0.25, {r -> 0.25, x[1] -> 0.75, x[2] -> 0.749409, x[3] -> 0.25, 
y[1] -> 0.25, y[2] -> 0.75, y[3] -> 0.250385}}*)

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[], 
  Rectangle[], {FaceForm[Red], Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r], {i, n}]} /. 
   sol[[2]]}]
```

[image]

**Obviously the result `r=0.25` isn't optimal and deviates from @cvgmt answer. Don't know why!**

**addendum case n=8**

The following optimum is only evaluated, if an additional constraint  `x[1] == r,y[1] == 1 - r`  is added

```
reg = Rectangle[];
n = 8;
sol = NMaximize[{r, 
Map[SignedRegionDistance[RegionBoundary[reg]], 
Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, n}]] >= r, 
Table[{x[i], y[i]} \[Element] reg, {i, 1, n}], 
Table[EuclideanDistance[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}] >= 2 r, {i, n}, {j, i -1}]
, x[1] == r,y[1] == 1 - r }, {r, Table[x[i], {i, n}], Table[y[i], {i, n}]} //Flatten,
Method -> {Automatic, "DifferentialEvolution", "RandomSearch","SimulatedAnnealing"; "NelderMead"}[[2]]]
(*{0.17054, {r -> 0.17054, x[1] -> 0.17054, x[2] -> 0.5, x[3] -> 0.5,x[4] -> 0.829459, x[5] -> 0.258819, x[6] -> 0.17054,x[7] -> 0.829459, x[8] -> 0.741182,y[1] -> 0.82946,y[2] -> 0.741181, y[3] -> 0.258817, y[4] -> 0.170541,y[5] -> 0.499999, y[6] -> 0.17054, y[7] -> 0.829459, y[8] -> 0.5}}*)

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[],Rectangle[], {FaceForm[Red], Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, r], {i, n}]} /.sol[[2]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Method->"DifferentialEvolution"` option.

Comment: Thanks, "DifferentialEvolution" and "SimulatedAnnealing" evaluate the "right" optimum!